# How to enable IntelliSense with vue 3.0 + typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

Using the composition API of vue 3.0, I am creating a vue component that exports three variables (functions): setPlayList, setStatus, status.

Please tell me how to type define the function that should have been exported

[image]